# How to generate SPARQL query to extract the publisher type?

Tags: sparql

How to generate SPARQL query to extract the publisher @type from a RDF like the one below? It should extract "Organization". It should find the first "publisher" block and extract the value for @type.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json" class="yoast-schema-graph">{
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@graph":[
      {
         "@type":"NewsArticle",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/#article",
         "isPartOf":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/"
         },
         "author":[
            {
               "@type":[
                  "Person",
                  "Organization"
               ],
               "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#/schema/person/0ff21dc6a12a5d2a33b89bf38893ab87",
               "name":"Sarah Perez",
               "description":""
            }
         ],
         "headline":"Twitter (now X) CEO Linda Yaccarino claims usage at &#8216;all time high&#8217; in memo to staff",
         "datePublished":"2023-07-24T17:15:10+00:00",
         "dateModified":"2023-07-24T18:14:49+00:00",
         "mainEntityOfPage":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/",
            "@type":"WebPage"
         },
         "wordCount":988,
         "commentCount":0,
         "publisher":{
            "@type":"Organization",
            "name":"TechCrunch",
            "logo":{
               "@type":"imageObject",
               "url":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/themes/techcrunch-2017/images/logo-json-ld.png",
               "width":"600",
               "height":"60"
            }
         },
         "image":{
            "@type":"ImageObject",
            "url":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/x-logo-beheads-twitter-logo.jpg?w=680",
            "width":680,
            "height":383
         },
         "thumbnailUrl":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/x-logo-beheads-twitter-logo.jpg",
         "keywords":[
            "Apps",
            "social",
            "Twitter",
            "X"
         ],
         "articleSection":[
            "Apps",
            "Social"
         ],
         "inLanguage":"en-US",
         "potentialAction":[
            {
               "@type":"CommentAction",
               "name":"Comment",
               "target":[
                  "https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/#respond"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "copyrightYear":"2023",
         "copyrightHolder":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#organization"
         },
         "description":"Twitter, now X&#8217;s, newly established CEO Linda Yaccarino touts the company&#8217;s success and X&#8217;s future plans in a company-wide memo obtained by CNBC. The exec once again claims, without sharing any specific metrics, that the service&#8217;s usage is at an &#8220;all time high,&#8221; and hints at what&#8217;s to come in terms of new product experiences [&hellip;]",
         "speakable":{
            "@type":"SpeakableSpecification",
            "cssSelector":[
               ".alpha",
               "#speakable-summary"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "@type":"WebPage",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/",
         "url":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/",
         "name":"Twitter (now X) CEO Linda Yaccarino claims usage at 'all time high' in memo to staff | TechCrunch",
         "isPartOf":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#website"
         },
         "primaryImageOfPage":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/#primaryimage"
         },
         "image":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/#primaryimage"
         },
         "thumbnailUrl":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/x-logo-beheads-twitter-logo.jpg",
         "datePublished":"2023-07-24T17:15:10+00:00",
         "dateModified":"2023-07-24T18:14:49+00:00",
         "inLanguage":"en-US",
         "potentialAction":[
            {
               "@type":"ReadAction",
               "target":[
                  "https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "isAccessibleForFree":"True",
         "hasPart":{
            "@type":"WebPageElement",
            "isAccessibleForFree":"True",
            "cssSelector":".paywall-content"
         }
      },
      {
         "@type":"ImageObject",
         "inLanguage":"en-US",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/07/24/twitter-now-x-ceo-ceo-linda-yaccarino-claims-usage-at-all-time-high-in-memo-to-staff/#primaryimage",
         "url":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/x-logo-beheads-twitter-logo.jpg",
         "contentUrl":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/x-logo-beheads-twitter-logo.jpg",
         "width":3200,
         "height":1800,
         "caption":"Image Credits: Bryce Durbin / TechCrunch"
      },
      {
         "@type":"WebSite",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#website",
         "url":"https://techcrunch.com/",
         "name":"TechCrunch",
         "description":"Startup and Technology News",
         "publisher":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#organization"
         },
         "alternateName":"TC",
         "potentialAction":[
            {
               "@type":"SearchAction",
               "target":{
                  "@type":"EntryPoint",
                  "urlTemplate":"https://search.techcrunch.com/search?p={search_term_string}"
               },
               "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
            }
         ],
         "inLanguage":"en-US"
      },
      {
         "@type":"Organization",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#organization",
         "name":"TechCrunch",
         "alternateName":"TC",
         "url":"https://techcrunch.com/",
         "logo":{
            "@type":"ImageObject",
            "inLanguage":"en-US",
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#/schema/logo/image/",
            "url":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/tc-logo-2018-square-reverse2x.png?resize=1200,1200",
            "contentUrl":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/tc-logo-2018-square-reverse2x.png?resize=1200,1200",
            "width":1200,
            "height":1200,
            "caption":"TechCrunch"
         },
         "image":{
            "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#/schema/logo/image/"
         },
         "sameAs":[
            "https://www.facebook.com/techcrunch",
            "https://twitter.com/TechCrunch",
            "https://mstdn.social/@TechCrunch",
            "https://bsky.app/profile/techcrunch.bsky.social",
            "https://www.threads.net/@techcrunch"
         ]
      },
      {
         "@type":"Person",
         "@id":"https://techcrunch.com/#/schema/person/0ff21dc6a12a5d2a33b89bf38893ab87",
         "name":"Sarah Perez",
         "description":"",
         "url":"https://techcrunch.com/author/sarah-perez/"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you mean something like that? `PREFIX schema: <https://schema.org/> select  ?publisher_type { ?article schema:publisher ?publisher . ?publisher a ?publisher_type }` - for multiple articles you should indeed also select other variables from the query to keep track of the relations between article and publisher type.

Comment: @UninformedUser How can I make that query more flexible, so it doesn't have be an article?

Comment: The query has no restrictions on articles, I guess my variable naming is confusing you? I just gave them speaking names to get a better understanding of what the query does with respect to the sample data you've provided. But technically, it only gather the relationship between any entity and its publisher (via `schema:publisher` property), and then gets the type (aka class) of the publisher.

Comment: could have also formulated the query more abstract: `PREFIX schema: <https://schema.org/> select  ?publisher_type { ?x schema:publisher ?publisher . ?publisher a ?publisher_type }` where the variable `?x` has the same meaning as `?article` or ... - it is just a place holder for a binding matching your RDF data graph.

Comment: @UninformedUser Unfortunately, that query is removed nothing for that code. Both of them

Comment: ok, I messed up the prefix declaration `http:` vs `https:`, my bad - sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2):

The correct query was:

```
PREFIX : <http://schema.org/>
    
SELECT ?publisherType
WHERE {
?article :publisher ?publisher .
?publisher a ?publisherType .
}
```